# Перемещение по заданным секторам

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-n-drop

Постараюсь максимально доступно описать задачу. У меня есть круг, который разделен на сектора (например 6). Так же, поверх этих секторов есть некая область, которая другого цвета и занимает площадь одного сектора.

Суть задачи: мне нужно сделать перемещение этой области по секторах, то есть как бы выбирая над каким сектором она будет. То есть, как draggable, только по секторам.

Может кто делал такое, подскажите